TypeError: (intermediate value).setName(...).setDescription(...).setDMPermissions is not a function
I'm new to discord.js and I tried making a test command for my discord bot. Now I got an error tho
[ERROR] An error occured inside the command registery:
 TypeError: (intermediate value).setName(...).setDescription(...).setDMPermissions is not a function

This is my code:
const {SlashCommandBuilder, PermissionFlagsBits} = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
     .setName('test')
     .setDescription('Test if everything is working.')
     .setDMPermissions(false)
     .addSubcommandGroup((subcommandgroup) => 
        subcommandgroup
         .setName("user")
         .setDescription("Configure an user.")
         .addSubcommand((subcommand) => 
            subcommand
                .setName("role")
                .setDescription("Configure an user's role.")
                .addUserOption((option) => 
                    option
                    .setName("user")
                    .setDescription("The user to configure.")
            ),
        )
        .addSubcommand((subcommand) => 
            subcommand
                .setName("nickname")
                .setDescription("Configure an user's nickname.")
                .addStringOption((option) => 
                    option
                    .setName("nickname")
                    .setDescription("The nickname the user should have.")
                .addUserOption((option) => 
                    option
                    .setName("user")
                    .setDescription("The user to configure.")
            
                ),
            )
        )
        .addSubcommand((subcommand) => 
            subcommand
                .setName("message")
                .setDescription("Configure a message.")
        )
    )
    .toJSON(),
    userPermissions: [PermissionFlagsBits.ManageMessages],
    botPermissions: [PermissionFlagsBits.Connect],

    run: (client, interaction) => {
        return interaction.reply("This is a test command.")
    }
};

Please help me fix that :)
I tried making a test slash command for my discord bot
I tried adding things, removing things and even to merge some lines of the code that some people merge. I just can't figure out how to fix that issue, I'd be so glad if anyone could help me. Thank you very much.

The error is happening because the method name is misspelled with an extra “s”; the correct method name is setDMPermission:
setDMPermission(enabled: boolean | null | undefined)

new SlashCommandBuilder()
  .setName('test')
  .setDescription('Test if everything is working.')
  .setDMPermission(false)


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
